# Which the online project manager is best for php-development?

Tags: php, project-management

preferably free demo :)

In other words, I want to know who uses which project manager...

Comment: Please add some more details what the tool of your choice would need to be able to do.

Comment: Indeed, more details will need to be provided. There aren't many (non that I can think of anyway) PHP oriented project management suites. Essentially, if you're looking for good project management, most elements shouldn't be dependent on the language you're using. Features such as collaboration, source control, task management and scheduling are important. After a quick google, I found this link: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/open-source-project-management-software.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your choice of project management software is better predicated on your development methodology (agile, waterfall etc...) than the specific language used.